# При присвоении адаптера вью пейджеру приложение падает

Tags: android

В приложении я пытаюсь подключить фрагменты tabLayouty. Некоторые методы были помечены устаревшими и я их заменял рекомендуемыми, при этом менялся и импорт. В итоге запутался с библиотеками и сейчас приложение работает ровно до закомметированого кода. Ошибок никаких нет. Подразумеваю что проблема в импортах, с устаревшими методами все работало. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import rodionov.lll.bbb.R;
import rodionov.lll.bbb.adapter.TabAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUI();


    }

    private void setUI() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.poem_tab));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.favorite_tab));
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(fragmentManager, 2);
//     viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
//        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

//        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
//                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
//
//            }
//        });


    }


 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import rodionov.lll.bbb.fragment.FavoriteFragment;
import rodionov.lll.bbb.fragment.PoemFragment;


public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int numberOfTabs;

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new PoemFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FavoriteFragment();
            default:
                return null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfTabs;
    }
}
```

ну и код одного из фрагментов. пока там ничего нет

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import rodionov.lll.bbb.R;

public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {


    public FavoriteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);
    }

}
```

зависимости:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
```

Логи: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:106)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1004)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1152)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19244)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6113)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:811)
```

Comment: Прочтите пожалуйста, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и добавьте лог ошибки

Comment: Вы используете неинициализированную переменную. Замените `TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(fragmentManager, 2);` на `TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager, 2);`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо вам большое. Оформите как ответ, я его отмечу.